# Acquring a DOM element attributes without querying again the DOM and set also a default value if doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, dom

I get a DOM element using:

```
a = document.querySelector('[data-time]');
```

I want to check if the element has some other specific attributes.

If they have I want to get their value or set a default value.

I can use:

```
c = a.querySelector('[data-time-pre])
```

but I call for each attribute the DOM.

So I thought of using:

```
placeholder = a.attributes.placeholder
```

So, in this case what is the simplest way to allocate a default value if the attribute doesn't exist.

I found `hasOwnProperty('property1')` but I'm not sure the attribute I'm looking for are inherited, plus I need to use multiple `ifs` if I have many attributes.

Maybe there is something like:

```
placeholder = (a.attributes.placeholder, 'default')
```

Comment: what do you mean to "exist"? being `undefined`? if so, what's wrong with `placeholder = a.attributes.placeholder === undefined?'default':a.attributes.placeholder`?

Comment: @Adelin "exist" , a number of attributes are set on a html element; depending on context their number differs. Depending of their values I take some decisions(ifs).If the attribute is not found I want to set a default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what you can do:

- Structure your attribute names and default values as k/v pairs.
- [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) of the attribute/default pairs.
- If the key doesn't exist as attribute, set it with it's default value.
- Return the existing or set attribute.

```js
const el = document.querySelector('#el')

const attrs = {
  // key : default value
  ['data-foo']: 'foo',
  ['data-bar']: 'bar',
  ['data-baz']: 'baz'
}

const results = Object.keys(attrs).map(key => {
  if (!el.hasAttribute(key))
    el.setAttribute(key, attrs[key])
   
  return { attr: key, value: el.getAttribute(key) }
})

console.log(results)
```

```html
<div id="el" data-foo="hello-world"></div>
```